# using Cloudflare rocket loader with 'strict-dynamic' csp

Tags: javascript, cloudflare, content-security-policy

I'm trying to use cloudflare's rocket loader and other various services(like email obfuscation) with `'strict-dynamic'` in my CSP. I'm running into a issue where since 'strict-dynamic' is present none of cloudflare's services can run. I looked at the official docs but they have nothing about 'strict-dynamic'. Is there some way to resolve this issue?